# Infer type of non-type template argument

Tags: c++, type-inference, template-meta-programming

I'm not great at template metaprogramming, so apologies if this is a dumb question.

I have a type like

```
template<int n>
struct S
{
  typedef decltype(n) type_of_n;

  // ...
};
```

and I'd like to write functions that look something like

```
template<
  typename T, 
  typename T::type_of_n n,
  typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, S<n>>::value>>
void f(const T &) { /* ... */ }
```

with the idea being that if the type of the non-type template argument to S changes at some point in the future (say to `std::size_t` or `int64_t` or something) then calling code will just continue working.  But I'm not sure how to get the compiler to infer both `T` and `n` in tandem here.

The only things I've come up with are basically hacks:

- Do something like `typedef int type_of_S_n` outside of `S`.
- Write something like `S<0>::type_of_n` instead of actually inferring the type

Is what I'm trying to do possible?  If not, is there a "cleaner" way to do it than the hacks above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to only accepts `S` and want to also deduce the value of `n`, then you can since c++17 use `auto` to deduce the type of a non-type template parameter.

```
template<auto n>
void f(const S<n> &) { /* ... */ }
```

You can also make it more generic and accept any type with a single non-type parameter by using a template template parameter.

```
template<template <auto> typename T, auto n>
void f(const T<n> &) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

> if the type of the non-type template argument to S changes at some point in the future (say to std::size_t or int64_t or something) then calling code will just continue working.

You can use the **placeholder type** `auto` with C++17 as shown below:

```
template<auto n>  //note the auto here
struct S
{
  typedef decltype(n) type_of_n;

  // ...
};
```

Comment: Hmm.  This is interesting but it seems to let me create instances with varying types of n, so e.g. `S<1>` and `S<1ULL>` are different types from one another.  I'm not sure this is what I want but I appreciate hearing about the feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a traits to know if a type is a `S<n>`:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_a_S : std::false_type {};

template <int N>
struct is_a_S<S<N>> : std::true_type {};
```

Then your SFINAE can be done like that:

```
template<
  typename T, 
  std::enable_if_t<is_a_S<T>::value, int> = 0>
void f(const T &) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

C++20 concepts make things easier

```
#include <concepts>

template<int n>
struct S {
  typedef decltype(n) type_of_n;
};

template<class T>
  requires std::same_as<T, S<typename T::type_of_n{}>>
void f(const T &) { /* ... */ }
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/r9MoPsfar)